# Combining multiple linear programming to minimize the sum

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have a math problem that looks like a bunch of linear programming problem combined where A matrix is shared.

Here is the math definition of my problem

Minimize

\begin{align}
& p_1 (x_{11} + x_{21} + \cdots + x_{m1}) +  p_2 (x_{21} + x_{22} + \cdots + x_{m2})  +  \cdots + p_n (x_{1n} + x_{2n} + \cdots + x_{mn})\\[6pt]
\\
\end{align}

where 
\begin{align}
& 0 \le  x_{11} + x_{21} + \cdots + x_{m1} \le t_{1} \\[6pt]
& 0 \le  x_{21} + x_{22} + \cdots + x_{m2} \le t_{1} \\[6pt]
& {}\qquad\vdots \\
& 0 \le  x_{mn} + x_{mn} + \cdots + x_{mn} \le t_{n} \\[6pt]
\\
\\
\\
& a_1 x_{11} + a_2 x_{12} +  \cdots + a_n x_{1n} \ge w_1 \\[6pt]
& b_1 x_{11} + b_2 x_{12} +  \cdots + b_n x_{1n} \ge k_1 \\[6pt]
& c_1 x_{11} + c_2 x_{12} +  \cdots + c_n x_{1n} \ge h_1 \\[6pt]
& 0 \le  x_{11} \le q_{11} \\[6pt]
& 0 \le  x_{12} \le q_{11} \\
& {}\qquad\vdots \\
& 0 \le  x_{1n} \le q_{1n}
\\
\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
& a_1 x_{21} + a_2 x_{22} +  \cdots + a_n x_{2n} \ge w_2 \\[6pt]
& b_1 x_{21} + b_2 x_{22} +  \cdots + b_n x_{2n} \ge k_2 \\[6pt]
& c_1 x_{21} + c_2 x_{22} +  \cdots + c_n x_{2n} \ge h_2 \\[6pt]
& 0 \le  x_{21} \le q_{21} \\[6pt]
& 0 \le  x_{22} \le q_{21} \\
& {}\qquad\vdots \\
& 0 \le  x_{2n} \le q_{2n}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\\
& {}\qquad\vdots \\
\\\\
& a_1 x_{m1} + a_2 x_{m2} +  \cdots + a_n x_{mn} \ge w_m \\[6pt]
& b_1 x_{m1} + b_2 x_{m2} +  \cdots + b_n x_{mn} \ge k_m \\[6pt]
& c_1 x_{m1} + c_2 x_{m2} +  \cdots + c_n x_{mn} \ge h_m \\[6pt]
& 0 \le  x_{m1} \le q_{m1} \\[6pt]
& 0 \le  x_{m2} \le q_{m1} \\
& {}\qquad\vdots \\
& 0 \le  x_{mn} \le q_{mn}
\\
\\
\\
\end{align}

Obviously, everything except $x_{ij}$ are given.

Can I solve this as one large LP where my I assume I have variables are $m*n$ for $x$ and solve one big LP? $m$ are around 100 and $n$ is about 5000. I guess an LP with 500,000 variables not small.

I don't think that I can solve every segment independently and assume the result is going to minimize the target cost function specially that there are dependencies between $x_{ij}$ because of the first rule so all the segments are not independent

How do I solve without building a large single LP?

Answer (score 0):

500,000 variables is large, but not out of the question if you have the memory to store all the coefficients. And because of the very sparse structure, it looks like you have only a few million coefficients. I'd say that's doable.

Let's put some specific numbers to it. Suppose our solver's standard form is
\begin{array}{ll}\text{minimize}&c^Tx\\\text{subject to}&Ax\leq b\end{array}
and $b$, $c$ requires 8 bytes per element and $A$ 16 bytes per *nonzero* element (4 bytes each for row & column, and 8 bytes for value; that's actually generous.)

- $c$: $mn$ variables = 500,000 entries = 4MB
- $b$: $2mn$ simple bounds, $2n$ coupling inequalities, $3m$ uncoupled inequalities = 1,010,300 entries $\approx$ 8MB
- $A$: $2mn$ simple bound nonzeros, $2mn$ coupling inequality nonzeros, $3mn$ uncoupled inequality nonzeros = 3,500,000 nonzeros = 84MB
- total: $\approx$ 96MB

Not even 100MB! *Psssshh.* And frankly, most modern LP solvers handle simple bounds more efficiently, so the total size of the model in practice is likely even lower. (Though what they do with those bounds when building a tableau or solving an interior-point Newton system depends on the implementation.)

By today's standards this is not a large LP. If you were solving a semidefinite or second-order cone program I'd feel differently; but a competent LP solver on a modern machine should be able to solve this problem efficiently.